# How to handle redirect response properly when using Nginx as proxy server, django as backend

Tags: django, nginx

I have a Django application and recently I need to launch a beta version. I want to keep the current running application untouched, and redirect all request starts with "/beta" to the beta app, with the help of Nginx. Here is my conf

```
    location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 360;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}

location /beta/ {
    rewrite ^/beta/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 360;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
}
```

This works, but there is a problem, when the app returns a 301 response, mostly when user needs to login to access some resource, the URL becomes the old one.

For example, if `/events` is login required.

http://example.com/beta/events   ->  http://example.com/login?next=/events/

How can I fix this without changing the application code? (Nginx solution?)

Comment: should you not handle it in the django backend/middleware instead of nginx ?

Comment: using subdomain beta.example.com is a better solution as for me

Comment: do I understand correctly that you are using Django's built-in development server as the backend for the proxy? you really shouldn't do it. If you were using, for example, uwsgi, your problem would have a pretty simple solution (and your app would work much faster)

Comment: Since django isn't aware of your nginx configuration, it can't build links which are aware of `/beta/`. The only difference between a request to `/foo that was redirected to a request to the base app `/foo` is the referrer. You'll have to sniff the referrer and prepend `/beta/` if you find the user originated from /beta/ or something

Comment: @DmitryDemidenko Yes, I know, but I don't want to setup a subdomain for test purpose. Anyway thank you!

Comment: @karthikr I'm considering this solution, if nginx can't do that.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev Yes, I have tried gunicorn, still the same. I'll try uwsgi, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

try [proxy_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect).

> "This directive sets the text, which must be changed in response-header "Location" and "Refresh" in the response of the proxied server."

so

```
    proxy_redirect http://example.com/ http://example.com/beta/;
```

of course, this only applies to redirects issued by the proxied server. I'm also assuming all redirects have the same problem.

tip: you can use more than one proxy_redirect directive, if necessary.

Comment: I had a similar situation with NGINX proxying Tomcat and having NGINX secured with SSL, proxying traffic to Tomcat's standard connector (using plain HTTP), Tomcat kept on redirecting traffic to the http: URL of the site (as much I was redirecting it back to https: I wanted to skip that extra hop).

This worked like a charm in that scenario too. I'm proxy_redirecting all http: responses from tomcat to the https: counterparts. Beautiful!